# Programmaticaly spoofing an http script request in an iframe

Tags: http, redirect, iframe

I'm building a backend admin system which edits json files that control the look and feel of the main site. I want to add a 'preview' button before the user hits save. To do that, I want to use the main site, but instead of calling the actual json file in production, save a temp version of it and redirect this user's traffic for that file to the temp file - from the original site code.

i've considered both chrome pluggins, configuring iframe somehow or, in worst case scenario, grabbing the production front-end, parsing out the call to the prod json file and replacing with new temp json file. That is obviously not ideal as it would entail a lot of work and if anything changes on the prod site, this will have to be updated.

I would love your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the main site's source code? You could implement a preview option from the main site which accepts a GET parameter and uses a temporary JSON setting based on this GET parameter.

From the backend admin system's point of view, it's just a matter of adding the JSON as part of the ajax GET request.

---

Unfortunately though, there is no easy way of doing this if you don't have access to the main site's source code or if you can't reach out to whoever maintains that main site.

Your cleanest option might be to recreate the main site's look and feel instead and pass it off as a "preview".

Comment: Thank you, Jerome!

Comment: I do have access to the site but we don't want to change it. We don't want to change the main site just for this tools functionality. So that's a no-go.

Comment: How about recreating a hardcoded sample page of the main site instead? Should the users be able to navigate the preview? If not, you could probably just host an HTML copy of the main site with the JSON settings applied.

If the main site updates often in which case you really have to access the main site's frontend, you could try out [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).